# При перелистывании карт сохраняется состояние переменной

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Есть виджет карточки на dart + flutter. При перелистывании карт состояние isExpanded сохраняется, что не правильно. Как сбрасывать это состояние? Пакет flutter_card_swiper. Пробовал и через коллбэк, и через сеттер, возможно что-то не так делал.

```
class ExampleCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Person candidate;

  const ExampleCard(
    this.candidate, {
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<ExampleCard> createState() => _ExampleCardState();
}

class _ExampleCardState extends State<ExampleCard> {
  bool _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return GestureDetector(
      onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
        if (details.delta.dy < 0) {
          setState(() {
            _isExpanded = true;
          });
        }
        if (details.delta.dy > 0) {
          setState(() {
            _isExpanded = false;
          });
        }
      },
      child:  Container(
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
              spreadRadius: 3,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: const Offset(0, 3),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(widget.candidate.imageUrl), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  gradient: const LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [Color(0xFFD7E9F7), Color(0xFFD7E9F7)],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            AnimatedContainer(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              curve: Curves.easeInOut,
              height: _isExpanded ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
              child:  Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: CustomPaint(
                          painter: MyLinePainter(),
                          size: const Size(40, 3),
                        ),
                      ),
                    Text(
                      '${widget.candidate.name}, ${widget.candidate.age}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    if (_isExpanded)
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          'About me: ${widget.candidate.aboutMe}',
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему добавив уникальные ключи

```
final cards = candidates.map((candidate) => ExampleCard(candidate, key: ValueKey(candidate.id))).toList();
```